# Hide the "Add new Item" option below the sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: web-part, list, sharepoint-foundation, toolbar

I have a sharepoint 2010 list, I want to hide the option "add new item" which resides below the list, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it?  Is it for security or are the items added elsewhere?

Comment: Hi Dave, we dont want users to add items from the link below...but they can add items to the list thru a custom webpart but not thru the link below

Comment: Have you already managed the ribbon buttons? Do you need an answer about how to apply a HideCustomAction feature?

Comment: Is this the solution for you? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224936/how-to-remove-listview-items

Comment: You can check below link if using sharepoint 2013 later
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62978074/10403065

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There's an out-of-the-box way to remove the `Add new item` link. If you edit the webpart properties using the `Modify Shared Web Part` command, you'll find the `Toolbar Type` dropdown in the `List Views` section. If you choose `No Toolbar` there and save the page, the footer link will be gone.

No code required, no unghosting/customization, *and no effect on other web parts that would be added on the same page*.

But you'll have to do this in every view, while the CSS way proposed by Hameds could be applied globally.

Comment: Perfect thank you.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want to hide it, you can use following css (you must override sharepoint core css with your custom css file)

```
td.ms-addnew{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to make the change globally, you could use a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) on the desired page. Edit the HTML source of the CEWP and insert Hameds' code inside a style tag:

```
<style>
    td.ms-addnew { display:none; }
</style>
```

Comment: how to add multiple add new item with? for ex : if i have two content type it has to show multiple "add new item"

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that there is a bug in SP2010 where if the toolbar type is set to "none" - if you have custom action ribbon buttons which target your library by list template ID or by content type ID, these buttons will not appear at the root folder of the library, but they will inside folders or document sets.

I have encountered this when deploying list definitions with toolbar type set to none; I have not tested this if you deploy a list and subsequently change the toolbar type to none.

Comment: Please use connect.microsoft.com to log this and get official verdict from MS: bug or not. Anyway, thanks for sharing this.

Comment: I checked. It's the same problem even after you deploy a list & subsequently change the toolbar type to none. Also found that if we add CEWP to the view, view dropdown is not coming in breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a page and including the list as a web part, then you just have to select the no toolbar option in toolbar type, this option is available when you choose edit web part.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('.ms-list-addnew').get(0).childNodes[1].nodeValue = " "
```